# Error when starting tor

Tags: tor

I'm using CentOS 64bit OS, the last time I use tor it's running 100%

but today I'm trying to run it, And I can't what I'm doing is :

```
service tor restart

Stopping tor.../etc/init.d/tor: line 144: kill: (17009) - No such process
failed.
Starting tor... tor is already running.
```

when I'm trying to stop it :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/tor stop

Stopping tor.../etc/init.d/tor: line 144: kill: (17009) - No such process
failed.
```

when I'm trying to start it :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/tor start

Starting tor... tor is already running.

sudo /etc/init.d/tor status

tor is not running
```

Also I try to kill all tor function :

```
killall tor

tor: no process killed
```

I'm using it with proxychains4

How can I fix it ?

thnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your startup script for Tor (`/etc/init.d/tor`) and determine the PID file (probably `/var/run/tor/tor.pid`).

If there is any Tor process running, try killing it.

```
ps aux | grep tor
```

If you see any Tor process, issue `kill -9 xxx` where `xxx` is the process ID.

Then delete your Tor pid file from above `rm /var/run/tor/tor.pid`.

Try starting Tor again.